# Word for a mage who protects his kingdom

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a title for a mage or wizard who has sworn to protect the people in his kingdom. He does not reign over the kingdom himself, but is rather their protector. Is there any established word or title from history or fantasy stories this mage could be called?

Comment: I would say that your word *protector* is perfect as the second meaning shows: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/protector.

Comment: Maybe a _maegis_? :)

Comment: Bilbo said to Smaug: "Lots… and none at all."

The structure of terms like Grand Vizier and High Priest(less) gives a big clue but our solid Earth has 200 countries and thousands of tongues, let alone the infinite worlds of fantasy.

Half a hundred years ago a poetical guide to writing science fiction advised “… take an empire that was Roman…” If Guardian Mage or Master Wizard or High Warlock won’t do, why? Why not use a place-filler, to change later?

Then, the sole function of a king is to… uh… protect the kingdom, though he has as much right to magical as military or medical help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The World of Warcraft movie uses "Guardian" or "The Guardian" if that could be of any help.

Comment: ... and an evil counterpart might be termed a **Warlock**

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you want archaic words here, but I think this may be an appropriate place for **weard**, from old english.

> Weard: guardian, watchman.

I like it just because I associate the word "ward" with a protection spell cast by a wizard.

As given in the definition of weard, **guardian** is a perfectly acceptable word too, as in "**guardian** of the kingdom". **Keeper** sounds more like a title than guardian does, so may be worth considering too.

Comment: While I really like the word, but I doubt that people will recognize/unterstand it.

Comment: That is completely fair, I just figured this might be a better chance to use archaic english than most because you're in a (presumably) archaic setting. I added some extra suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The mage is the **tutelary figure** of the kingdom.

> "Tutelary" definition: having the position of guardian or protector of a person, place, or thing
>
> Example: *Rinaldo Locatelli has passed away this Wednesday 8 July
>   2015. « He was a great servant of the Council of Europe and of the European idea as well as a tutelary figure for the whole Congress"
>   stated the President of the Congress, in a message of condolence to
>   his wife.*

Answer (score 0):

> In contemporary literature and pantomime, the "Grand [**Vizier**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vizier)" is a character stereotype and is usually portrayed as a scheming backroom plotter and the clear power behind the throne of a usually bumbling or incompetent monarch.
>
> A well-known example of this is the sinister character of Jafar in the Disney animated film *Aladdin*, who plots and uses magic to take over the entire Kingdom of Agrabah under the nose of the nation's naïve sultan, just as Jaffar in the 1940 movie *The Thief of Bagdad* dethroned his master, caliph Ahmad.
>
> Others include Zigzag from *The Thief and the Cobbler* (the original inspiration for the character of Jafar in Disney's *Aladdin*), the comic book character Iznogoud, Prince Sinbad's advisor Yusuf in the DC Vertigo series *Fables*, and the villains of the video games *Prince of Persia* and *King's Quest VI: Heir Today, Gone Tomorrow*.